# Select specific columns with repository in Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a big table with a binary column for picture. I need to show contents of this table in a view and make it searchable. I have tried only selecting a subset of columns that are needed in this. However, the generated SQL always has all the columns of the table in the generated query.

```
public IQueryable<ApplicantDTO> GetApplicantQueryable()
{
    return DataContext.Applicants
           .Include(a => a.Nationality)
           .Select(x => new ApplicantDTO
                            {
                                Id = x.Id,
                                BirthDate = x.BirthDate,
                                Gender = x.Gender,
                                FirstName = x.FirstName,
                                LastName = x.LastName,
                                OtherName = x.OtherName,
                                MobileNo = x.MobileNo,
                                Age = x.Age,
                                Nationality = x.Nationality.National,
                                Admitted = x.admitted,
                                Completed = x.Completed
                            })
           .Where(a => a.Admitted == false && a.Completed == true)
           .OrderBy(a => a.LastName)
           .AsNoTracking();
    }
```

But instead of just specifying the above rows, the generated SQL from profiler is

```
SELECT 
    [a].[Id], [a].[BirthDate], [a].[BirthPlace], [a].[CompleteDate], 
    [a].[Completed], [a].[ContentType], [a].[CreateDate], 
    [a].[Denomination], [a].[Disability], [a].[Email], 
    [a].[FirstName], [a].[Gender], [a].[HomeTown], [a].[LastName], 
    [a].[MarryStatus], [a].[MatureApp], [a].[MobileNo], [a].[NationalityID], 
    [a].[OtherName], [a].[Passport], [a].[Pin], [a].[PostalAddress], 
    [a].[Region], [a].[Religion], [a].[ResAddress], [a].[SerialNo], 
    [a].[Title], [a].[VoucherID], [a].[admitted], [a.Nationality].[National] 
FROM 
    [Applicants] AS [a] 
INNER JOIN 
    [Nationality] AS [a.Nationality] ON [a].[NationalityID] = [a.Nationality].[Id] 
WHERE 
    ([a].[admitted] = 0) 
    AND ([a].[Completed] = 1) 
ORDER BY 
    [a].[LastName]
```

With all the underlying columns all included in the query.

I tried putting it in an anonymous type before casting it to the `ApplicantDTO` but still the same effect.

What's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that's the entire outermost query sent to SQL?  I would expect a subquery that looks like that, but an outer query that selects fewer columns.

Comment: Thought so as well, but have debugged severally and that's it

Comment: With the navigation, EF core is projecting all the columns.  This is a SQL code generation issue in EF Core (there are lots).  Either check if this is fixed in the latest EF Core 2 bits, or workaround by selecting the nationality with a second query instead of using the navigation property.

Comment: Note as well, that if you are selecting into a projection then you do not need the `.Include()` statement - it will be ignored.

Comment: Have you tried to use linq query ?

Comment: Excluding include still presents the same list of columns, will give the linq query a try

Comment: Have tried linq query and the columns are still returning all, will try @DavidBrowne-Microsoft suggestion to update to ef core 2 and see if that solves it

Comment: While this is Inner Join and not left join but perhaps something is causing materialization of both the sides of join in EF Core. (something related to issue like this https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6647). It is likely to be fixed in 2.0 release.